# Как записывать только изменившиеся данные с помощью утилиты dd

Tags: linux, ubuntu

В целях тестирования часто приходится перезаписывать большой (~120 Гб) образ на флеш накопитель (128 гб). Так как флешка имеет свой ресурс перезаписи, не хотелось бы так опрометчиво к этому относится. Можно ли указать в утилите dd, что бы перезаписывались только отличающиеся в адресе памяти байты, а одинаковые байты пропускал? Что бы не перезаписывать по факту одно и тоже.

Comment: Почему на флешку?

Comment: так rsync вроде как для подобного и предназначен, попробуйте так: 

`rsync -vh --progress --inplace -no-whole-file ...`

Comment: Возможно тебе поможет пакет `zsync`.

Answer (score 3):

Перезаписывать изменения dd    копий можно торрентом. Создайте торрент файл с раздела который копируете и запустите раздачу. Запустите второй клиент торрента и этот торрент файл. Укажите расположение данных и клиент начнет проверять блоки. Найдет изменения и запросит их с первого клиента.

Comment: Хитро придумано

Comment: Звучит костыльно, но, наверное, это самый простой вариант, что бы не кодить  и не искать другие утилиты. Торрент конечно блоками проверяет, а не побайтово. Или можно настроить побайтово?

Comment: Тут ещё проблема обменяться пирами) вообще тут можно решить в 8 строчек на питоне, но без костылей не интересно

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически можно написать такой скрипт, но вероятно эффективнее было бы расширить [исходники `dd`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/dd.c)

В самой утилите есть возможность пропуска `байт/блоков` размер  задан в `bs`  как во входном - опция `skip`, так и результирующем - опция `seek`, файлах.

простейший пример:

test.txt

```
Lorem1ipsum
```

out.txt

```
Lorem ipsum
```

команда запишет в  out.txt начиная c 5 позиции единицу

```
dd if=test.txt of=out.txt bs=1 seek=5 skip=5 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

`if=test.txt` - входной файл

`of=out.txt` - выходной файл

`bs=1`  - размер блока 1 байт

`seek=5` - пропустить в выходном файле 5 байт (начать запись с 6-ой позиции)

`skip=5` - пропустить во входном файле 5 байт (начать считывать с 6-ого)

`count=1` - размер перезаписываемой области (`count * bs` байт)

`conv=notrunc` - опция конвертации которая позволяет не обрезать окончание файла сразу после записанного блока иначе файл `out.txt` выглядел бы так:

```
Lorem1
```

Что можно сделать:

1. сравнить побайтово старый и новый файл, записать третий в качестве промежуточного где 0 это отсутствие изменений 1 изменение. Далее, на основе примера выше мы получаем файл:

   `00000100000`
2. преобразовать промежуточный файл в данные:

   `diff = [5, 1, 0, 0]`

сначала идет смещение, потом количество записываемого, в конце всегда `[0, 0]`

```
5 - смещение (количетво нулей)  // offset
1 - длина записываемого (количество единиц) // size
0 - смещение (записываем 0 если нули идут до конца файла)
0 - длина записываемого (при достижении конца файла записываем 0)
```

Запись можно представить в псевдокоде без оптимизации таким циклом, если длина записи `size` равна 0 завершаем программу:

```
i = 0;
offset = diff[i];
size = diff[i + 1];
while(offset + size != 0){
  seek = offset;
  skip = offset;
  count = size;
  write(seek, skip, count);   
  i += 2;
  offset = diff[i];
  size = diff[i + 1];
}
```